# Allow user to delete their entries

Tags: php, jquery, sql, wordpress, mysqli

I have this code which builds a table based on SQL date from the user (their posts):

```
<table>
             <?php
$table_name =  "candle_number";
$data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `userid` = '{$current_user->ID}';" );
$i=1;/* to what purpose?? */
foreach( $data as $rs ){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td><strong>{$rs->dname}</strong></td>
        <td>{$rs->dateenglish}<br>{$rs->datehebrew}</td>
        <td><!-- /* Notice the various dataset attributes here */ -->
            <a href='#' data-name='{$rs->dname}' data-dod='{$rs->dateenglish}' data-hdod='{$rs->datehebrew}'>
                <img width=50 height=50 src='http://www.mountsinaiparks.org/digital-yahrzeit/wp-content/themes/yahrzeit-theme/bootstrap/images/Candle01.gif' class='img-responsive candle' alt='Yahrzeit Candle' style='margin:auto !important;' />
            </a><br>
            <p style='text-align:center !important; margin:-10px 0 0 0 !important; padding:0; line-height:7px !important;'><span style='color: #f26522 !important; font-size:10px !important; font-weight:700 !important;'>CLICK TO LIGHT</span></p>
        </td>
        <td><a href='delete.php?id=$id'>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

which has an href to delete.php:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql_ = "DELETE FROM msparks_wp3.candle_number WHERE id = '$id'";
mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Database error!');
header('location:MYURL');
?>
```

And the last TD displays a "DELETE" url that is supposed to remove that specific row - but it is not working. I was thinking of using a different method, but I cannot find the right way to make it NOT delete all of the table contents.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Sorry - removed. I do apologize, I am front end trying to muscle my way through some urgent parts for a site I designed.

Comment: Yes, it just goes right back to the page without deleting the entry.

Comment: OH! No there's no id in the link! THat's it!

Comment: Okay yes, the ID is passing through, but the php isn't working.

Comment: Did you try like this? <td><a href='delete.php?id={$id}'>Delete</a></td>

Comment: you can refer wp hook no need custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was rather interesting. I used a combination of $wpdb function and basic SQL:

```
<?php
//WP Stuff
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/digital-yahrzeit/wp-load.php' );

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DB_NAME";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$id = $_GET['id'];

$id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
$table_name =  "candle_number";
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `id` = '$id'" );

mysql_close($conn);

header('location:MY_HEADER');
?>
```

Thank you all who answered.